# Index out of bounds in for cycle (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

Ok, I'm having a problem (probably a newbie problem) but here it goes:

```
for i=1:1:16;
    h=10^(-i);
    yDFC2(i)=(1/(2*1*h(i)))*(-1*valX+valX);
end
err2=abs(fDX(x1)-yDFC2);
loglog(h,err2,'b-');
```

Every time I run this code, it gives me the following error:

> Attempted to access h(2); index out of bounds because numel(h)=1

`valX` is a variable calculated by determining the image of a function that has been inputted by the user; `fDX` is the derivative of that function (both are working well).

This is meant to plot the spacing (`h`) vs the error in central finite differences (CFD). The formula inside the for cycle is the 1st order derivative calculated by CFD for `n=2`.

The spacing needs to be in increments of `10^(-i)`.

If anyone could help me figure this out, I'd be very thankful.

Answer (score 3):

If you do

```
h = 10.^(-(1:1:16));
```

outside of the for loop, you can accress h(i) correctly inside. The problem is that you create a scalar h for each pass.

Comment: Alternately, you could change the first line of the for loop to `h(i)=10^(-i)`. I believe this is slightly for inefficient, but for 16 iterations, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: True, but as he wants to use the h vector for plotting later, it's good to have it available.

Comment: The vector will be available after, I think its just inefficient to add an element to a vector every iteration.

Comment: Ah, yes of course; h might be growing inside a loop. Consider preallocating for speed :)

Comment: Well, I did what you said and now I get a blank graph.
I placed 
    `h = 10.^(-(1:1:16));` 
outside of the for cycle and I maintained everything equal except for that. Anyone know what's the matter? I'm completely lost in here.

Comment: I assume you have also removed the h=10^(-i); from inside the loop. What could be causing the problem now is yDFC2 taking on negative or zero values. With the minus sign in -valX+valX, all your values will be zero: (A-A)/(h) = 0 for all h and A. Your formula must be wrong?